# How to determine the memory imbalance?

Tags: linux, memory, performance-monitoring

I administer some servers. In some time I determine what some servers have low performance (three times less).

I started to understand why 
I identified what one servers have different memory modules (4GB, 8GB, 16GB). 
These modules naturally had different number of ranks, CAS and frequency.

How to determine this situation in Linux ?

It seems to me that the memory subsystem should somewhere say that the memory modules are different, the frequencies are different and it can not use the modules in the group that the memory subsystem goes into a certain compatibility mode (and get low performance).

Now I get low performance and Linux cant speek me about different nocompatibility memory modules.

Where similar can be seen in Linux?
Maybe this can be seen through the PCM hardware counters ?
Or somewhere else ?

Comment: If you're looking for installed hardware either `dmidecode` or your out-of-band management interface (e.g. HP's ILO) should give info regarding installed memory modules. Determining how well it performs might be a different story

Comment: Yes I can determine this by dmidecode or ipmitool sel list or /var/log/mcelog. But I am interesting to deep look to this problem. How can I found roots of problems by PCM or Linux. Where memory subsystem tells of its mode and your problems

Answer (score 0):

Is it a NUMA system? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250034/numa-balancer-in-linux maybe. On NUMA systems, it is possible to get degraded performance if you are continually bouncing across NUMA domains. That being said, the scheduler *should* do the right thing most of times.

Comment: Yes Its NUMA system but my problem with different performance memory modules. 
In one case it depend with different type/ranks of memory modules in one server.
In second case (I found it now) some memory modules have different performance in one server. With this modules Linpack give vary low performance
I think Linux or PCM registers will be get info about submemory state or mode of work this is modules.